# One more Wordpress logged out issue

Tags: wordpress

OK, I'm comming here after reading several tutorials to avoid wordpress to loggout but still with no solution. My problem is that I'm logged out if I quit the browser and launch it again. I speak about the user area as the wp-admin is accessible even if I first try to access the user area.
First I did a simple test with a php file like that on the same server:

```
<?php
setcookie("test","value",time()+3600);
print $_COOKIE['test'];
?>
```

The cookie is printed after a browser restart.
I add that in my theme functions.php file:

```
add_filter('auth_cookie_expiration', 'identifie_pour_longtemps', 99, 3);
function identifie_pour_longtemps($seconds, $user_id, $remember)
{
    $expiration = 365*24*60*60;

    return $expiration;
}
```

Then I checked the cookie expiration date in my browser that is set to next year.

Finally I checked the browser cookie after a restart and it is still there with the same expiration date. But I still need to login again.

EDIT: I find that the theme I use checks the use logged in with `$_SESSION['user_logged_in']` instead of `is_user_logged_in()` so I have to replace all.
Is there a file in a theme that is loaded first to put that:

```
$_SESSION['user_logged_in']=is_user_logged_in();
```

Comment: Just because you still have the same key I gave you a year ago, doesn’t mean I have not switched the locks in the meantime … Meaning, WP might have other mechanisms to have a session “expire” after a certain time interval. Looking at the code of `wp_validate_auth_cookie()`, it seems to check against a timestamp that was stored inside the cookie itself. Not sure if that hook you are using changes _that_ as well, or if you’d have to interfere in another place as well. I’d start by checking what the code that _sets_ this cookie does.

Comment: Please see my edit... maybe the theme functions.php file is good ?

Comment: Hm, is that something WP itself is writing to the session, or does that come from somewhere else? If the latter, then just setting it with the line you suggested above might be dangerous. Without figuring out what the exact purpose of this value is, I would not really recommend this.

Comment: Can you explain how it can be dangerous ? That variable is set to true by wordpress after a successful login attempt.